# Django Rest Framework permission_classes not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem using Django Rest Framework's permission_classes attribute.
The view I want to protect is defined as:

```
class Test(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsLoggedIn]

    def get(self, request):
        return Response("aaa")
```

I have also tried having the class inherit GenericAPIVIew.

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsLoggedIn(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False
```

I'm trying to get the permission to at least always refuse the request, but it seems that the has_object_permission method is never getting called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the **`has_permission(...)`** method instead of `has_object_permission(...)`

```
class IsLoggedIn(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return False
```

Comment: Wow, why is this not documented? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I think it is already there, [check this out](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Answer (score -1):

I found this in drf offical document:

*Limitations of object level permissions
For performance reasons the generic views will not automatically apply object level permissions to each instance in a queryset when returning a list of objects.
Often when you're using object level permissions you'll also want to filter the queryset appropriately, to ensure that users only have visibility onto instances that they are permitted to view.
Because the get_object() method is not called, object level permissions from the has_object_permission() method are not applied when creating objects. In order to restrict object creation you need to implement the permission check either in your Serializer class or override the perform_create() method of your ViewSet class.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.